# How to display URL in lower case?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, webforms

I have a webforms projects with uppercase URLs being returned to the client:

```
http://www.looknbook.com/Packages/Forms/package_search.aspx
```

The requirement is to have the URLs display in lowercase:

```
http://www.looknbook.com/packages/forms/package_search.aspx
```

How do I send URLs to the client's browser in lowercase in ASP.NET Webforms?

Answer (score 5):

For IIS7, you can use URI Rewrite and use the example [here](http://en.hugon.ws/articles/iis7/url-rewriting-for-seo-convert-force-urls-to-lower-case/):

```
<rule name="Convert to lowercase" stopProcessing="true">  
    <match url=".*[A-Z].*" ignoreCase="false" />  
    <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:0}}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: This almost works for me but it ignores any query string capitalisation. Is it possible to lowercase the query string name value pairs as well?

Answer (score 2):

Classic ASP .NET paths correspond to folder names, and folders are not case-senstive in Windows.
Thefefore, both lowercase and capitalized URLs can be used to access your site.

The only reason you see an capitalized URL in the address bar is because **the links have it capitalized**. Change all links on the site to be lowercase, and that's it.

If you also want to *force* lowercase (i.e. change to lowercase even if the user entered a capitalized URL), you'll need to do URL rewriting but concrete solutions depend on the version of IIS you're using.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to achieve lower case URL from code site than we can achieve that by implementing following code in Application_BeginRequest or Application_EndRequest of global.cs page

```
            var curenturl = Request.Url.ToString();           
            if (Regex.IsMatch(curenturl, @"[A-Z]"))
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
                Response.StatusCode = 301;
                Response.AddHeader("Location", curenturl.ToLower());
                Response.End();
            }
```