# URL Rewrite to change querystring case

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I am looking to setup a URL rewrite rule in my web.config that will modify the following URL:

```
/detail.aspx?aID=164&mode=t
```

To (see case of `aid`):

```
/detail.aspx?aid=164&mode=t
```

Please can anyone assist me with this? The only other thing to mention here is that the rule should still work if there is no `mode` parameter at the end and irrespective of what order the `aid` parameter appears in the querystring.

**EDIT 1**

I found this guide which rewrites the whole URL to lowercase. This would work for me only the accepted solution seems to ignore the query string values.

[How to display URL in lower case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009944/how-to-display-url-in-lower-case)

**EDIT 2**

I'm now using the following to issue a 301 redirect when uppercase characters are found. the accepted answer addresses the original question but this solution works on the full URI, domain, path and querystring.

```
        '301 REDIRECT ON UPPERCASE URIS
        Dim fullUri As String = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
        If fullUri.Any(Function(c) Char.IsUpper(c)) Then
            Response.RedirectPermanent(fullUri.ToLower)
        End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:
You are right, did not realize it was same page.
You need to add another condition.

```
 <rule name="URL Lower" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(detail.aspx?)(.*)" />                        
      <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
          <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)" />
          <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="([A-Z]+)" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="detail.aspx?{ToLower:{C:1}}" appendQueryString="false" />
 </rule>
```

Examples:

/detail.aspx?aID=164&mode=t
converts to
/detail.aspx?aid=164&mode=t

and /detail.aspx?aid=164&mode=t is ignored because of second rule.

Comment: This creates a recursive redirect loop :(

Comment: Works perfectly and accepted as it answers the original question. Even though for now I'm sticking with the code in EDIT 2 as it address the case of the full URi.