# IIS Rewrite Rule for Lower Case URL's

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I have a IIS Rewrite Rule to convert all URL's to lower case

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="LowerCaseRule1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

However it only converts a part of the url to lowercase and does not convert querystrings. For example ID is not coverted to id

```
http://www.itsmysitesitesite.com/showproduct.aspx?ID=230
```

How can I modify the above rule to include query strings too?

Comment: although it may not be a problem, shouldn't you be careful ? Are you 100% sure that case is never important in your querystrings ?

Comment: After a bit of searching this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018553/url-rewrite-to-change-querystring-case might help you out?

Comment: @Bartdude important? Can you elaborate.

Comment: @Damon yeah I think that's what I need. but I do not want to make too many changes. Just a change in the config I already have. Can you help?

Comment: @user1089173 > Well, let's imagine you're passing search terms through querystring, it might be important for you to differentiate "MySearchTerm" and "mysearchterm", and in that case you wouldn't want the parameters to be rewritten. In other words : while on IIS the URL case isn't important, the querystring case might be. Now I don't know your situation/site, maybe that's just a useless remark, but maybe it's something you overlooked.

Comment: a +1 from my end for your explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my comment (referencing[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018553/url-rewrite-to-change-querystring-case) question) I would imagine the rule would look something like this:

```
<rule name="URL Lower" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />                        
      <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
          <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)" />
          <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="([A-Z]+)" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}{ToLower:{C:1}}" appendQueryString="false" />
 </rule>
```

A disclaimer though, I'm working on Windows XP so I've only got IIS 6.0, so I can't check the syntax is correct! Might require a bit of tweaking...

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to make one rule that would capture both the `{URL}` and `{QUERY_STRING}` and also display the url the way I wanted it to. So, I split it into two rules.

**URL to Lowercase**

```
<rule name="UrlToLowercase" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*[A-Z].*" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions>                          
      <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="POST" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
      <add input="{URL}" pattern="^.*\.(axd|css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|txt|xml|svg|pdf)$" negate="true" ignoreCase="true" /> 
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" />
</rule>
```

**URL with Query String to Lowercase**

```
<rule name="UrlWithQueryStringToLowercase" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">   
      <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)" /> 
      <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern=".*[A-Z].*" ignoreCase="false" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="POST" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{ToLower:{URL}}?{ToLower:{C:0}}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

This should cover every case and if it doesn't, please let me know. :)

I added some extra conditions that you may want to leave in or take out.

`<add input="{URL}" pattern="^.*\.(axd|css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|txt|xml|svg|pdf)$" negate="true" ignoreCase="true" />` ignores paths that end in axd, css, js, jpg, ...etc. Without this rule, you will not be able to load a file with uppercase letters from your server.

`<add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="POST" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />` will ignore requests with a POST method. Without this rule, POSTs that specify uppercase urls will lose data because of the 301 (GETs do not have this problem).